# why an update query is not working?

Tags: oracle, jsp, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I have an update query in a servlet. The syntax is is correct, but when I execute the query, nothing happens. The execution stays frozen and the command never ends. Minutes later the message "ADVERTENCIA: GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8080(5)." is printed every couple of seconds

I have tried with:

```
con.stmt.executeUpdate ("SQL");
con.rset = con.stmt.executeQuery ("SQL");
```

and with PreparedStatement.

This is the query:

```
System.out.println(""
                    + " UPDATE JSP_TABLE SET "
                    + " field1        = '" + request.getParameter("input1") + "',"
                    + " field2= '" + request.getParameter("input2") + "',"
                    + " field3= '" + request.getParameter("input3") + "',"
                    + " field4= '" + request.getParameter("input4") + "',"
                    + " field5= '" + request.getParameter("input5") + "',"
                    + " field6= '" + request.getParameter("input6") + "',"
                    + " field7= '" + request.getParameter("input7") + "',"
                    + " field8= '" + indicador + " VS " + request.getParameter("input8") + "',"
                    + " field9= '" + request.getParameter("input") + " al " + request.getParameter("hasta9") + "'"
                    + " WHERE ID_PK = " + request.getParameter("inputPK"));
```

All my Statements, ResultSets and Connections are closed at the end of use.
I have a second update which works fine.

```
    package Funciones;

    import conexion.conectar;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    public class ActualizarDinamica extends HttpServlet {

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            conectar con = new conectar();
            try {
                /*
                 * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
                 */
                con.stmt = con.conn.createStatement();

                String indicador = "";
                switch (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("indicador"))) {
                    case 1:
                        indicador = "Nivel de Servicio";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        indicador = "Venta";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        indicador = request.getParameter("txt_otro");
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        indicador = "Presencia";
                        break;
                };

                 /* way 1   
                  * con.rset = con.stmt.executeQuery(""
                        + " UPDATE JSP_TABLE SET "
                        + " FIELD1        = '" + request.getParameter("input1") + "',"
                        + " FIELD2           = '" + request.getParameter("input2") + "',"
                        + " FIELD3          = '" + request.getParameter("input3") + "',"
                        + " FIELD4  = '" + request.getParameter("input4") + "',"
                        + " FIELD5         = '" + request.getParameter("input5") + "',"
                        + " FIELD6       = '" + request.getParameter("input6") + "',"
                        + " FIELD7          = '" + request.getParameter("input7") + "',"
                        + " FIELD8         = '" + indicador + " VS " + request.getParameter("input8") + "',"
                        + " FIELD9     = '" + request.getParameter("input9") + " al " + request.getParameter("input10") + "'"
                        + " WHERE FIELD_PK = " + request.getParameter("input11_ID")); 

              con.rset = con.stmt.executeQuery(""
                        + " UPDATE JSP_TABLE2 SET"
                        + " FIELD_DATE =  TO_DATE('" + request.getParameter("input12") + " " + request.getParameter("input14") + ":" + request.getParameter("input13") + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')"
                        + " WHERE FIELD_ID = " + request.getParameter("input11_ID"));

*/


              /*  way 2
                con.stmt.executeUpdate(""
                        + " UPDATE JSP_TABLE SET "
                        + " FIELD1        = '" + request.getParameter("input1") + "',"
                        + " FIELD2           = '" + request.getParameter("input2") + "',"
                        + " FIELD3          = '" + request.getParameter("input3") + "',"
                        + " FIELD4  = '" + request.getParameter("input4") + "',"
                        + " FIELD5         = '" + request.getParameter("input5") + "',"
                        + " FIELD6       = '" + request.getParameter("input6") + "',"
                        + " FIELD7          = '" + request.getParameter("input7") + "',"
                        + " FIELD8         = '" + indicador + " VS " + request.getParameter("input8") + "',"
                        + " FIELD9     = '" + request.getParameter("input9") + " al " + request.getParameter("input10") + "'"
                        + " WHERE FIELD_PK = " + request.getParameter("input11_ID"));


                con.stmt.executeUpdate(""
                        + " UPDATE JSP_TABLE2 SET"
                        + " FIELD_DATE =  TO_DATE('" + request.getParameter("input12") + " " + request.getParameter("input14") + ":" + request.getParameter("input13") + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')"
                        + " WHERE FIELD_ID = " + request.getParameter("input11_ID"));
                     */

                //way 3
                PreparedStatement updateSmallQuery = null;
                PreparedStatement updateBigQuery = null;

                String bigQuery=
                        ""
                        + " UPDATE JSP_TABLE SET "
                        + " FIELD1        = '" + request.getParameter("input1") + "',"
                        + " FIELD2           = '" + request.getParameter("input2") + "',"
                        + " FIELD3          = '" + request.getParameter("input3") + "',"
                        + " FIELD4  = '" + request.getParameter("input4") + "',"
                        + " FIELD5         = '" + request.getParameter("input5") + "',"
                        + " FIELD6       = '" + request.getParameter("input6") + "',"
                        + " FIELD7          = '" + request.getParameter("input7") + "',"
                        + " FIELD8         = '" + indicador + " VS " + request.getParameter("input8") + "',"
                        + " FIELD9     = '" + request.getParameter("input9") + " al " + request.getParameter("input10") + "'"
                        + " WHERE FIELD_PK = " + request.getParameter("input11_ID");

                String smallQuery= ""
                        + " UPDATE JSP_TABLE2 SET"
                        + " FIELD_DATE =  TO_DATE('" + request.getParameter("input12") + " " + request.getParameter("input14") + ":" + request.getParameter("input13") + "','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')"
                        + " WHERE FIELD_ID = " + request.getParameter("input11_ID");
                try {
                    con.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                    updateSmallQuery = con.conn.prepareStatement(smallQuery);
                    updateBigQuery = con.conn.prepareStatement(bigQuery);
                    updateBigQuery.executeUpdate();
                    updateSmallQuery.executeUpdate();
                    con.conn.commit();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("catch!");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    if (con != null) {
                        try {
                            System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                            con.conn.rollback();
                        } catch (SQLException excep) {
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (updateSmallQuery != null) {
                        updateSmallQuery.close();
                    }
                    if (updateBigQuery != null) {
                        updateBigQuery .close();
                    }
                    con.conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                }
                response.sendRedirect("sol_env_c.jsp");

            } finally {
                con.conn.commit();
                con.conn.close();
                con.stmt.close();
                out.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this help to find the answer.
PD: The small one run with no problems. the big one it's the problem.

EDIT:

This is conectar()

```
public conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC driver loaded ok.");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(params, user, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `con`, `stmt` and `rset`?  Could you show a bit more of the code.  The code you're showing only prints out a query string, it doesn't actually perform a query...

Comment: a Statement and a ResultSet parameters from "MyConnection" class, and "con" is the object for the servlet.

Comment: yes, but how are they created?

Comment: In MyConnection.java

`public Connection conn = null;
 public ResultSet rset = null;
 public Statement stmt = null;`


And in UpdateServlet.java

    `MyConnection con = new MyConnection();
    con.stmt = con.conn.createStatement();
    //rest of the code`

Comment: `"field=9 '"` doesn't look right; have you pasted this straight from your code, and is it identical to what you tried to execute? I doubt that would parse. Do you have any error handling? Did the prepared statement version use bind variables? Showing the whole code block might be useful.

Comment: my bad (fixed now), they are just  generics names to show the qwery.
There is no errors, no SQLException, no nothing. only the eternal execution and the "WARNING: GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8080(5)." a few minutes later.

Comment: Assuming the SQL is actually valid, and you can run the output from the `println` directly in the DB without issue, then the problem must be in a part of the code we can't see. If I had to guess, I'd suspect you're getting an error but swallowing it somewhere, and are not closing the connection in a `finally`. Not sure we can help unless you can show all the code.

Comment: Full code of the servlet now.
@AlexPoole

Comment: ALARM: [possible SQL injection attack hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Can you show your conectar() method?

Comment: First: BalusC has told you something really important. You should switch to using prepared statements. Second: It sounds like you are waiting on locks in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Bill is almost certainly correct and you just have a lock on rows you're trying to update. You mentioned that 'the syntax is correct', which suggests you might have checked it directly in the database - e.g. with SQL*Plus or SQL Developer - and have not issued a `rollback` (or `commit`) in that session. Attempting to update the same rows from your code is then hanging waiting for the locks to be released.

If you can find the session where you ran the update manually, issue a `rollback` in it. If you can't, you can see which sessions are holding locks with a query like:

```
select vs.osuser, vs.process, vs.logon_time, vs.sid, vs.serial#, vs.program,
    dl.lock_type, dl.mode_held, dl.blocking_others
from dba_locks dl
left join v$session vs on vs.sid = dl.session_id
where lock_type != 'Media Recovery'
and lock_type != 'Redo Thread';
```

While your code is running - and hung - you can see what's blocking it with something like:

```
select vsw.osuser, vsw.process, vsw.logon_time, vsw.sid, vsw.program,
    dw.lock_type, dw.mode_held,
    vsh.osuser, vsh.process, vsh.logon_time, vsh.sid, vsh.serial#, vsh.program
from dba_waiters dw
left join v$session vsw on vsw.sid = dw.waiting_session
left join v$session vsh on vsh.sid = dw.holding_session;
```

Or search for other examples, e.g. [this](http://oracleexamples.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/find-a-locking-session/). You need privileges to query the `v$` performance views, and if you don't have them you may need DBA assistance. If you can't manually rollback the lock you might need DBA help to kill the locking session anyway.

You should really pay attention to the comments about parameterising your statements, too.